# send private replies keep asking for pages_messaging while my token already have that permission

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to send private replies to comments on a page, I get user token with

$

```
fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => FB_APP_ID, 
 'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
 'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['leads_retrieval','email','publish_pages','manage_pages','pages_show_list','pages_messaging','pages_manage_cta','read_page_mailboxes','pages_messaging_subscriptions'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('//abc.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

the I create token for page as following

```
$requestxx = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $fbApp,
    $token,//my user access token
    'GET',
    '/pageID?fields=access_token',
    array('ADMINISTER')
  ;
$responset  = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest( $requestxx );
$json           = json_decode( $responset->getBody() );
$page_access_token    = $json->access_token;
```

then I debugged my page token and it has "pages_messaging", permission but when I try to send private reply to a comment I get

Graph returned an error: (#230) Requires pages_messaging permission to manage the object

My code to send private replies

```
$fb->post('/comment_id/private_replies',$message,$page_access_token);
```

I am stuck here for three days, please help me

Comment: Is your app live, or in development mode? If the latter, does the user you are trying to reply to have a role in the app?

Comment: my app is in development mode, and I am the admin of app so it should work